# PRINTDLG structure used on an hWnd that isn't the same process

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi

The following compiles without errors or warnings but doesn't snag the IEFrame window, or at least I know it fails to change that window's print orientation to landscape:

```
PRINTDLGEX pd;
pd.lStructSize = (DWORD)sizeof(PRINTDLG);    
BOOL GetPrinterDeviceDefaults(struct tagPDA* pd);

BOOL bRet=AfxGetApp()->GetPrinterDeviceDefaults(&pd); 
pd.hwndOwner = FindWindow("IEFrame", NULL);
LPDEVMODE pDevMode = (LPDEVMODE)::GlobalLock(&pd.hDevMode);
pDevMode->dmOrientation = DMORIENT_LANDSCAPE;
::GlobalUnlock(&pd.hDevMode);
```

I have evidence the code may have acquired the hWnd of the IEFrame window because the results of `MessageBox(0,(LPCSTR)pd.hwndOwner,"[header]",MB_OK);` displays some text gobbledygook in the msg. instead of nothing.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is that your actual code?  Because you're not actually calling `GetPrinterDeviceDefaults`, you're just declaring its prototype.

Comment: Thank you for replying, Adam.  I've just added BOOL bRet=AfxGetApp()->GetPrinterDeviceDefaults(&pd); underneath the prototype (and above the FindWindow statement), and then ran the hook containing the code.  Subsequently, as soon as I launch Explorer, I get an OS memory conflict error dialog.  I can't move beyond that.

Comment: Um, after you set `pd.hwndOwner`, you don't do anything with it, so it doesn't matter what you set it to. I think you misunderstand what the `hwndOwner` is for. It doesn't specify the window you want to get the defaults from. it's just the owner window for the print dialog UI.

Comment: Thanks for reading this Raymond. I've never used this PRINTDLG API before, and I'm having some difficulty understanding what to do. (C++ is not my 'first language' either.) What you said in your two sentences is informative.  I have misunderstood what hwndOwner is for.  My intentions: from the DLL this code resides in, I wanted to open the print dialog UI (hopefully invisibly) of Internet Explorer and change its setting to landscape.  It thought this would do that; now I'm not sure about what potential solution would.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not at all familiar with the PRINTDLG API you're trying to use, but your MessageBox code is all wrong.

The [`MessageBox` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645505%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) takes two pointers to null-terminated C strings (either ANSI strings or Unicode strings, depending on whether `UNICODE` is defined by the preprocessor).  You're passing in a window handle instead, which is not a null-terminated C string of any type -- it's just an opaque data value that only has meaning to the kernel.  So when `MessageBox` tries to interpret the string, it gets a pointer to who-knows-where, and it will either crash with an access violation or read random gobbledygook out of memory until it runs into a stray NUL byte.

Ordinarily the compiler will give you an error here, but by inserting the cast you're telling "it's OK, I know what I'm doing, I promise this is really an `LPCTSTR`", which masks the error.

The correct fix to this is to print the handle value into a character array.  For example:

```
#define DIM(x) (sizeof(x)/sizeof((x)[0]))
wchar_t handleStr[64];
_snprintf_s(handleStr, DIM(handleStr), _TRUNCATE, "Handle value: %p", (void*)pd.hwndOwner);
MessageBoxW(NULL, handleStr, L"[header]", MB_OK);
```

Comment: Adam, thank you very much for this.  I'm trying to learn as much as I can about C/C++ and other low level mechanics which I'm not ordinarily accustomed to working with.  What you wrote is really informative and helpful.